# Woocommerce review section outside of tab (on single-product page) wont' show comments?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce, hook

I am working on a custom theme, so what I have done so far is:

1. I removed the review tab in the Woocommerce single product page because I replaced it with 5 custom tabs and I want to write my custom section just below ('woocommerce_after_single_product_summary').
2. I copied the 'single-product-reviews.php' template for editing and called it in my theme's functions file. That all seems to work fine.
   [This is how it looks.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYT2f.png)

As you can see everything reads fine except for the comments themselves. There are reviews/comments posted, I tested it multiple times manually and from Dashboard, I just can't get them to show up. The star rating shows up on the products themselves, even on the shop page after you write the review, so it obviously works. It might be a simple mistake, I might just be too tired to notice it. I will post the code, if anyone has any solutions, thanks in advance.

Btw the reviews and comments are enabled everywhere in the Dashboard, I checked it many times. This is the div/code that is causing the problem, I have not edited the file at all besides changing the title.

```
    <?php if ( have_comments() ) : ?>
        <ol class="commentlist">
            <?php wp_list_comments( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_review_list_args', array( 'callback' => 'woocommerce_comments' ) ) ); ?>
        </ol>

        <?php
        if ( get_comment_pages_count() > 1 && get_option( 'page_comments' ) ) :
            echo '<nav class="woocommerce-pagination">';
            paginate_comments_links(
                apply_filters(
                    'woocommerce_comment_pagination_args',
                    array(
                        'prev_text' => is_rtl() ? '&rarr;' : '&larr;',
                        'next_text' => is_rtl() ? '&larr;' : '&rarr;',
                        'type'      => 'list',
                    )
                )
            );
            echo '</nav>';
        endif;
        ?>
    <?php else : ?>
        <p class="woocommerce-noreviews"><?php esc_html_e( 'There are no reviews yet.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Does any of that markup show up? Or just not the comments? Check `var_dump(have_comments());` and see if you are getting a true or false value. Also _As you can see everything reads fine except for the comments themselves._ - we don't actually know if everything is fine, since we don't know the expected output - and since the comments aren't showing up, it's probably not fine :)

Comment: Markup is alright. I completely forgot about doing var_dump and it seems you're right, it returns false. Any ideas? Like I said the comments do get saved in the dashboard though, and the product itself counts the reviews/comments + reads average rating and star rating above the product itself (all on the single-product page). EDIT: also the WP comments_template() function does read the comments and shows them normally, if that helps at all. I'm still new to Woocommerce :)

Comment: My guess is because the `comments_template` hasn't been called. If you check out the documentation for [`have_comments`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/have_comments/) it says that it will return `false` until `comments_template` has been called. `have_comments` also relies on the comments being in the main loop. We'd have to see how you're actually calling this in `functions.php`.

Comment: Am I supposed to call it in my theme's functions? Not sure how it's supposed to be done. I appreciate the replies, I'll try some stuff out later and report how it goes